# Прогрузка информации с бд на вторичных Window на старте приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Собственно, есть два окна, `Window` и `TempWindow`. На втором таблица, подгружаемая с бд, конкретно - с MSSQL локально. Второе окно открывается при нажатии кнопки на первом.

И проблема вот в чём - на подгрузку бд при первом открытии окна `TempWindow` тратится заметная секунда. А при его закрытии и повторном открытии бд отображается мгновенно. Значит, даже при закрытом `TempWindow` загруженная бд где-то хранится. И значит, её можно загрузить, и не открывая `TempWindow`, в котором она будет отображена.

То есть хотелось бы уже при запуске основного Window прогрузить все запросы к бд на вторичных окнах, чтобы даже при первом их открытии бд отображалась моментально, а не целую секунду. Как к этому можно подойти?

*Ну либо можно как ускорить подгрузку с бд? Секунда - как-то слишком для локальной бд.*

Подгрузка в бд написана базово, в **TempWindow.xaml.cs**:

````
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable H1Table;

        public TempWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = "server = DESKTOP-1KILEEG; Trusted_Connection = Yes; DataBase = AlgonaDatabase;";
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.H1";
            H1Table = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                // установка команды на добавление для вызова хранимой процедуры
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertH1Section", connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HeadingName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "HeadingName"));       
                SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(H1Table);
                H1SectionsGrid.ItemsSource = H1Table.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }```
````

Comment: 1. Научитесь использовать асинхронность. 2. Научитесь использовать привязки. Когда это все поймете, ваша задача решится очень просто и без особых потерь производительности.

Comment: Первое открытие соединения занимает время (потом оно хранится в пуле). Разбор sql и составление плана занимает время (потом используется готовый план). В первый раз данные загружаются с накопителя (а потом они могут браться из кеша SqlServer'а в памяти).

Comment: Не стоит забывать о JIT-компиляции. На неё тоже тратится время. При повторном открытии окна используется уже готовый код. Вот в сумме и набегает секунда. Но это неточно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Понял, буду узнавать. 
Ну и вопрос на миллион: тут подобные вопросы от новичков удалять, можно как закрывать или оставлять прямо так?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, любопытно. И детально. Пока мало что понятно, буду разбираться, когда начну загружать большие объёмы данных. А то пока моё простейшее приложение грузит шесть строк дольше запроса на миллионы результатов в любом поисковике.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter.Fill довольно медленный. Хотя на шести строках это не должно быть заметно. А ещё адаптер сам открывает и закрывает соединение, можно убрать лишний код. | InsertCommand не используется в данном событии Loaded. Её можно создать и добавить позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, я не знаю про поведение БД, но зато знаю про всё остальное. Например, про привязку данных.

Поменяйте это

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="H1SectionsGrid" .../>
```

На это

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding H1Table}" .../>
```

То есть выкинуть имя и привязаться к `DataTable`, содержащей данные.

Теперь C# код можно переписать вот так с привязкой данных

```cs
public partial class TempWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string connectionString = "server = DESKTOP-1KILEEG; Trusted_Connection = Yes; DataBase = AlgonaDatabase;";
    private DataTable _h1Table; // не обращайтесь к этому полю, обращайтесь к свойству H1Table вместо этого

    public DataTable H1Table
    {
        get => _h1Table; 
        set
        {
            _h1Table = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TempWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.H1";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
            using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertH1Section", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            {
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HeadingName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "HeadingName"));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id") { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
                adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(dt));
                H1Table = dt;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await LoadDataAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Фишка привязки в том, что вы можете сколько угодно изменять и переприсваивать `H1Table` в коде, `DataGrid` будет обновляться в соответствии с этими изменениями.

Подождать, когда произойдет первое подключение все равно придется, но теперь за счет `async/await` ваше окно не будет в зависшем состоянии.

Далее, рекомендую вам познакомиться со зверем Entity Framework. Он умеет сам строить SQL запросы, с ним намного удобнее работать, чем с ADO.

Comment: Пробую поставить Entity Framework через Диспетчер пакетов NuGet в Visual Studio. 
Выводит ошибку "Не удалось установить пакет «Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.3». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой".

Гугл не помог. Этот "зверь" рассчитан на 2.1 и новее, но не может встать на любую из версий 2.0-4.8. 

Не встречались с такой проблемой?

Comment: @Альраун `Этот "зверь" рассчитан на 2.1` - **.NET Standard 2.1** != **.NET Framework** https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Я ставил, только он не учитывается из-за моего рейтинга <15.
Что до ".NET Standard 2.1 != .NET Framework", теперь я чуть больше запутался в вопросе, что выбрать: .NET Standard 2.1, .NET Framework или .NET 5.0.
Так и не нашёл вразумительной информации о том, пойдёт ли на 5.0 Entity Framework и в каких ситуациях прочие лучше чем 5.0. Пишется лишь "он не для всех серверных приложений лучше".
Есть мысли?

Comment: @Альраун если вам не принципиальна платформа, то выбирайте .NET 5, лучшего на данный момент нет. Под нее как раз Entity Framework 5 идет. .NET Framework 4.x уже считается устаревшим более не обновляется, для него выпускаются только обновления безопасности. .NET Standard - не для приложений, а для универсальных библиотек создан, и начиная с .NET 5 уже не актуален, можно забыть про Standard как что-то из прошлого.

Comment: Ура, заветная конкретика. Так и поступлю, thanks.